# Display Tag List alphabetically with a sections for each letter, including the empty letters that have no terms

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, tags, taglist

I would like to sort a tag list by alphabet with their corresponding letter. including the empty ones.

At the moment I'm listing only the letter that has tags but can't get them to display/sort alphabetically. Then I also have the issue of it not showing the empty letter in the alphabet. Also worth mentioning I added the asort() because it wasn't sorting correctly.

Working:

- adding an alphabetic separator and nesting its tags under it

Not working:

- sorting alphabetically
- adding empty alphabetic number as well with text "No tags to display for this letter"

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
   $args = array(
     'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
     'hide_empty' => false,
     'order' => 'ACS',
     'orderby' => 'slug'
    );
    $terms = get_terms($args);

                       
    $term_list = [];    
    foreach ( $terms as $term ){
      $first_letter = strtoupper($term->name[0]);
      $term_list[$first_letter][] = $term;
    }
    unset($term); 
    asort($term_list );?>
                    
   <div class="tag-wrap">

     <ul>
      <?php foreach ( $term_list as $key=>$value ) : ?>
         <li class="border-radius">
           <a href="#<?php echo $key; ?>"><h3><?php echo $key; ?></h3></a>
         </li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
     </ul>
  </div>

 <div class="tag-list">
    <?php
      asort($term_list );

      foreach ( $term_list as $key=>$value ) : ?>
         <div class="term-row" id="<?php echo $key; ?>">
            <div class="term-letter">
                <h3><?php echo $key; ?></h3>
            </div>
                                
            <div class="tag-items">
               <?php foreach ( $value as $term ): ?>
                    <div class="tag-item">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term );?>"><?php echo $term->name;?></a>
                    </div>
               <?php endforeach;?>
             </div>
         </div>
      <?php endforeach;?>
 </div>
```

Its displaying like this at the moment:
Tagwrap:
[Tagwrap output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBDn9.png)

Tag List:
Same sorting order as the above, its pretty much using the same php.

Comment: Hi LadyX, you misspelled the order value in your terms query, it's "ASC" and not "ACS", in addition, to sort alphabetically you have to use the order value "DESC". See this related post : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/210817/make-loop-display-posts-by-alphabetical-order

Comment: LadyX, I've added an answer below for how to get this to work while keeping the "empty" letters. Let me know if this works for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting the terms is not going to make a difference to what you are trying to do. If you want to include letters that are not in your results, then you can't use the results for your loop regardless of how it's sorted, because it can only loop through what's there.

Instead, we can simply loop on the alphabet and use the letter as the key to get the terms from your array.

First, loop through the alphabet to display the letters in your `tag-wrap` div:

```
$alphabet = range('A', 'Z');   // 1. use range to get the alphabet

<div class="tag-wrap">
   <ul>
     <?php
     // 2. display the regular alphabet instead of the letters from your results
     foreach ( $alphabet as $letter ) : ?>
         <li class="border-radius">
           <a href="#<?php echo $letter; ?>"><h3><?php echo $letter; ?></h3></a>
         </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Now we will again loop through the alphabet, and this time get the results from your `$term_list` using the letter as the key. If there are no terms, then you can display a message, otherwise you can display the list as you were before.

```
<div class="tag-list">
    <?php
      // 3. display the results by looping through the alphabet to ensure all letters are included
      foreach ( $alphabet as $letter) : ?>
         <div class="term-row" id="<?php echo $letter; ?>">
            <div class="term-letter">
                <h3><?php echo $letter; ?></h3>
            </div>
                                
            <div class="tag-items">
               <?php
                    // 4. Get the terms for this letter, if there are none show a message
                    $termsforletter = $term_list[$letter];
                    if (empty($terms for letter)) { ?>
                         <p>No Results for this letter</p>
                    <?php } 
                    else {
                        foreach ( $termsforletter as $term  ): ?>
                            <div class="tag-item">
                                <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $termsforletter  );?>"><?php echo $term->name;?></a>
                           </div>
                       <?php endforeach;
                    } ?>
             </div>
         </div>
      <?php endforeach;?>
 </div>
```

(Note: This code is untested but the general idea is there)

This also means that you don't have to worry about doing any sorts on your arrays because we are using the alphabet loop to sort thedisplay/

Comment: The for loop didn't work but I modified it a bit so it achieves the same result. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working one based on FluffyKitten's answer, just changed the check to display text if are no terms for the letter.

```
<?php
$alphabet = range('A', 'Z'); 

$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'slug'
);
$terms = get_terms($args);

   
$term_list = [];    
foreach ( $terms as $term ){
    $first_letter = strtoupper($term->name[0]);
    $term_list[$first_letter][] = $term;
}
unset($term); ?>
                
<div class="tag-wrap">

 <ul>
   <?php foreach ( $alphabet as $letter ) : ?>
     <li>
       <a href="#<?php echo $letter;  ?>"><h3><?php echo $letter;  ?></h3></a>
     </li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="tag-list">
<?php
 foreach ( $alphabet as $letter) : ?>
  <div class="term-row" id="<?php echo $letter; ?>">
    <div class="term-letter">
       <h3><?php echo $letter;?></h3>
    </div>
                    
    <div class="tag-items">
      <?php 
       $termsforletter = $term_list[$letter]; 
       if (empty($termsforletter )): ?>
          <div class="tag-item">
            <p>No topics matching this letter </p>
          </div>
       <?php else:
        foreach ( $termsforletter as $term ): ?>
           <div class="tag-item">
             <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term );  ?>"><?php echo  $term->name;  ?></a>
           </div>
                                        
        <?php endforeach;?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```